# Failed to load module script of type (.mjs)

Tags: javascript, next.js, remark42

I'm trying to integrate remark42 in my next js app but was unable to do so.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zddbd.png)

here is my configuration

```
`<script
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
__html:  var remark_config = { host: 'http://localhost:8080', site_id: 'remark', components:['embed'] }
}}
></script>
<script
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
   __html:  !function (e, n) { for (var o = 0; o < e.length; o++) { var r =        n.createElement("script"), c = ".js",  // Update the file extension to ".mjs" d = n.head || n.body;   "noModule" in r ? (r.type = "module") : (r.async = !0), (r.defer = !0), (r.src = remark_config.host + "/web/" + e[o] + c), d.appendChild(r); } }(remark_config.components || ["embed"], document);,
  }}
></script>
```

I'm trying embed comment engine in my next js app I m runing the binary remark42 in my localhost,

all the configartions are ok but browser keeps giving MIME type error, any suggestion how should I resolve this issue.